# Update textview font and reset it back to original Android

Tags: android, textview

I need to flash textview font depending on the value i am getting, either 1(blue) or -1(red). However i need to reset it back to white once flash is done. I think i have tried everything and truly stuck.

I tried ColorRunnable, but it only flashes at given time, not when item i get update coming through.

```
       if(direction != null){
            if (direction.equals("1")){
                tvCur.setTextColor(colorUp);
            }
            else if (direction.equals("-1")) {
                tvCur.setTextColor(colorDown);
            }
        }
        tvCur.setText("Test");
```

I tried adding  `tvCur.setTextColor(originalColor)` before and after if statement, but it just sets text to white and doesnot flash at all.

Thanks

EDIT.

I was wondering if i could use **Animation** to fade from **white -> red/blue -> white** instead of setting a color?

Comment: Just add another `else` statement after `else if`. to set White color to Text.

Comment: tried that before, it never enters that last else.Direction always 1 or -1. Its for the items in the listview so some values might get it consantly, some might only get it once every 5 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change with:

```
        if(direction != null){
        if (direction.equals("1")){
            tvCur.setTextColor(colorUp);
        }
        else if (direction.equals("-1")) {
            tvCur.setTextColor(colorDown);
        }else{

            tvCur.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    tvCur.setText("Test");
```